# Using isnan in template function

Tags: c++, templates, macros, gcc4

I have following code:

```
  template<int FORMAT>
  int double_to_bulk(double value,
                       char* buf,
                       double max_num,
                       int* state = NULL)
  {
     if (isnan(value))
     {
        //Something to do
        return 1;
     }
     //Something more to do
  }
```

And strange compilation error:

> myfile.h: In function ‘int double_to_bulk(double, char*, double,
>   int*)’:
>
> myfile.h:351: error: there are no arguments to ‘isnan’ that
>   depend on a template parameter, so a declaration of ‘isnan’ must be
>   available
>
> myfile.h:351: error: (if you use ‘-fpermissive’, G++ will
>   accept your code, but allowing the use of an undeclared name is
>   deprecated)

But I really don't want to use `-fpermissive`

I use `gcc 4.1.2`, quite old, but nothing to do with it. Why is it problem to use `isnan` in template function?

Comment: in C99 it exists as a macros. And yes, it was simply not defined. I just was confused by such strange compiler message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you don't have an available definition for `isnan`. Have you included in your source the appropriate header file where `isnan` is defined? Nothing at all here seems to depend on your template parameter.

Comment: Yes, moving it out to another function shows that it was not defined. I just was confused by such message of compiler.

Answer (score 0):

Adding the line `#include<cmath>` should fix the problem.

If any arguments did dependent on a template parameter (e.g. if one of the arguments had a template-parameter type), the compiler will only check for existence of `isnan` when you instantiate the template, which would probably cause an error anyway, just later, or potentially not at all if you never use the template.

DO NOT use `-fpermisive`, it would probably just delay the error to link time